# Updating $scope with multiple templates with same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following route:

```
.state('cloud', {
    url: '/cloud',
    views: { 
        'main': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' },
        'choices-header': { templateUrl: 'pages/templates/views/choices-header.html', controller: 'cloud' }
    }
})
```

I do this because I need my **choices-header** template to go into a different view then my **main** template.

`#options_header` in my **choices-header** template is supposed to show if `$scope.cloud_selected_items` has items in it.

But for some reason, when an item is added to the array, it doesn't know this, so the element doesn't show. However if I reload the page with an item in the array, it will show. So I know that the code is *working*.

Does anyone know what I need to do with my `cloudCheck()` function so that the scope *updates* and my template see's the change in my `$scope`?

So in my index page, I have:

```
<div ui-view="choices-header"></div>
<div id="pageContent">
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
</div>
```

---

**cloud.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="data in items">
   <div ng-click="cloudCheck(data.id)">Click me</div>
</div>
```

---

**choices_header.html**

```
<div id="option-header" ng-show="cloud_selected_items.length > 0">
    {{ cloud_selected_items.length }} selected
</div>
```

---

**javascript**

```
.controller('cloud', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.cloud_selected_items = [];

    $scope.cloudCheck = function(id) {
        $scope.cloud_selected_items.push(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you possibly make a plnkr?

Comment: I tried man but I couldn't get ui-router to work right. @Dinesh

Comment: you can try this: in both templates, add a debug div and print {{$id}}. Based on the config, I strongly suspect what you got is 2 instances of the controller which obviously do not share the state. If this is inadvertent then you have a simple fix.

Comment: I see that @AWolf has already pointed out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that the scope is not shared in your views. Scope will be inherited in nested views but you're having two separate views.

If you do `console.log($scope)` you'll see that cloud controller will run twice with different scopes. You can see that scopes are different by the scope property `$id`.

You can use a service that keeps track of your selected items. Then the two-way binding will update your header view as expected.

Please see code below (not working here, cookie issue with ui-router on SO) and here a working demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/rrgqy3xg/).

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
    .controller('cloud', function ($scope, $state, cloudService) {
        $scope.items = [{
            id: 1,
            data: 'test1'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            data: 'test2'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            data: 'test2'
        }]; //dummy data
        $scope.cloud_selected_items = cloudService.getItems();
        
        $scope.cloudCheck = cloudService.cloudCheck;
        /*function(item) {
            console.log(id);
            $scope.cloud_selected_items.push(item);
        };*/
})
.factory('cloudService', function() {
    var cloudSelectedItems = [];
    
    var cloudService = {
        cloudCheck: function(item) {
            cloudSelectedItems.push(item);
        },
        getItems: function() {
            return cloudSelectedItems;
        }
    };
    
    return cloudService;
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/cloud");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('cloud', {
        url: '/cloud',
        views: { 
            'main': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/cloud.html', controller: 'cloud' 
            },
            'choicesheader': { 
                templateUrl: 'partials/choices_header.html', 
                controller: 'cloud' 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/choices_header.html">
    <div id="option-header" ng-show="cloud_selected_items.length > 0">
    {{ cloud_selected_items.length }} selected
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/cloud.html">
    <div ng-repeat="data in items">
        <button ng-click="cloudCheck(data.id)">Click me</button>
    </div>
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ui-view="choicesheader"></div>
  <div id="pageContent">
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great man! My only issue I am having is in my **cloud.html**, if I try something like `ng-hide="cloud_selected_items.length > 0"` it doesn't work  when **choices_header.html**'s evaluation works.

Comment: Also, does this mean the cloud controller is run twice?

Comment: Yes, it's running twice. Maybe there is away with resolve to fix it but I have no fix yet. But I think it's OK that it runs twice. I can't see the problem with your expression in cloud html. Can you please fork/update the fiddle so I can see the issue?